# convert timestamp to date in hive and get data for that date

Tags: hive

I have a query like this

```
select distinct emp,phno,addrs,email from cdv.emp;
```

Now I want to get only data which is created on the latest generated date and not old. 
I have an audit column `created_on` - this is the unique key and Timestamp

select distinct emp,phno,addrs,email from cdv.emp;

I expect latest data based on `created_on(timestamp)` column which is generated in 24 hours or say the Max date

Answer (score 0):

Use `rank` analytic function.It will work much faster than IN subquery:

```
select distinct emp,phno,addrs,email
from
(
select emp,phno,addrs,email,
       rank() over(order by to_date(c.created_on) desc) rn 
  from cdv.emp c
)s
where rn=1;
```

If you want latest record per `emp,phno,addrs,email`, then you can use row_number() without distinct. If this method is applicable, this will be even faster:

```
select emp,phno,addrs,email
from
(
select emp,phno,addrs,email,
       row_number() over(partition by emp,phno,addrs,email order by to_date(c.created_on) desc) rn 
  from cdv.emp c
)s
where rn=1;
```